# Pass value from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I have searched all over the internet for a solution. I am wondering how I would pass this following code to php

```
           setTimeout(function () {
                // did it win??!?!?!
                var spin = _this.cache.wheelPos,
                    degrees = spin % 360,
                    percent = (degrees / 360) * 100,
                    segment = Math.ceil((percent / 6)),  //divided by number of segments
                    win = _this.cache.wheelMapping[segment - 1]; //zero based array

                console.log('spin = ' + spin);
                console.log('degrees = ' + degrees);
                console.log('percent = ' + percent);
                console.log('segment = ' + segment);
                console.log('win = ' + win);

                //display dialog with slight delay to realise win or not.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    alert('you won '+win+'!');
                }, 700);
```

I have tried

```
    setTimeout(function () {
                        $.ajax({
   url: 'test.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {"win" : +win},
   success: function(data) {
   }
});
}, 700);
```

i am testing this by writing it to a text file 
php file is:

```
<?php


$_SESSION['test'] = (isset($_POST['win']) ? $_POST['win'] : "";

if (empty($_SESSION['test']){
echo "nothing here";
}else{
$var = $_SESSION['test'];
file_put_contents("test.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
exit();
}
?>
```

which after realising i hadnt put anything in the function i set a alert which shows the following error

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in <b>/home/thegrpg/public_html/grpg/test.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

Comment: Does `success` run (check in the console)? Because it's not going to do anything if there is no code there.

Comment: sorry I realised that and have updated it but no it shows a error, please see original post

Comment: You need to start the session ( `session_start();` ) at the top of the page.

Comment: started my session but still the same error

Comment: You forgot to close your `(` Add a closing parentheses to the end: `(isset($_POST['win']) ? $_POST['win'] : "");`
`

Comment: Try to use this jquery code in php like that way.
echo "<script>alert('Something');</script>";
Like that way you will use your complete code in php file. Try this...

Comment: oops so i have twice in fact i forgot to close my if statement further down my php file but now i have done that it is showing that the $_SESSION['test'] is empty and also so is the $_POST

Comment: Is it supposed to be `data: {"win" : +win},` with `+win` other than just `win`? Also don't place it in an array.

Comment: With your syntax errors fixed have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: wow @SpencerWieczorek turns out it was that simple i took it out of the array and changed it to just win and it works thanks just shows not to always follow tutorials of the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Converting all my comments into an answer)*

Firstly to access sessions we need to call `session_start();` at the to of our PHP page. Then there is a missing closing `)` for the assignment of `$_SESSION['test']`:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = (isset($_POST['win']) ? $_POST['win'] : "");
/*                                                            ^ here */
...
?>
```

Then in the AJAX call we want to remove the `+` from `+win`. So change it from:

```
data: {"win" : +win},
```

To:

```
data: {"win" : win},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Data does not seem to be an Array.
Try

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'test.php',
 type: 'post',
 data: [{"win" : +win}]
});
```

Comment: thanks for you advice but this still shows a error which is in original post

Comment: There is a missing closing bracket $_SESSION['test'] = (isset($_POST['win']) )? $_POST['win'] : "";

Comment: Yes this was pointed out in the above comments I also missed another one further down. This has corrected the errors but the post as seasion are both showing blank after every thing you guys have said